# What does "drive a spike" mean?

Tags: meaning

what does drive a spike mean in this sentence :

It's like driving a spike through my heart

Comment: A spike is a large nail. If the phrase were _driving a nail through my heart._ what would you think it meant?

Answer (score 3):

Driving a stake through the heart was the traditional way to kill a vampire (and/or werewolf and/or zombie -- a folkloric creature that wouldn't die normally, but needed to be destroyed and kept that way). Note (from the comment below) that this was a way of "killing" someone who was already dead; a corpse which was believed to be a vampire or thereabouts would be exhumed, staked, and buried again.

(Customs were highly variable, though. This was a superstition, a folk or "underground" belief, which never had a universal form and was not looked on kindly by any Western religious authority -- Christian, Jewish, or Islamic -- that I've ever heard of.)

A spike is a large nail, the kind that was used to nail rails to ties in old-fashioned railroad construction.

Could this expression originally have been "drive a stake through the heart"?

Comment: I suspect that the method may have been occasionally used literally in the past, as a form of execution, but I would agree that the idiom probably comes from the vampire scenario.

Comment: I don't think it was ever used as a mode of execution. Vampires were corpses that were already dead and believed to be causing trouble (and werewolves were sometimes confused with them); the corpse would be exhumed, staked, and buried again. If I remember rightly, suicides were also sometimes buried with a stake through their heart as a preemptive measure.  Note: Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Pretty much every imaginable form of execution has been used at one time or another.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the problem is with the word ‘drive’.

It has [multiple meanings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drive) and in this particular case this one applies:

> 2.4 [with object] Force (a stake or nail) into place by hitting or pushing it:
>   *‘nails are driven through the boards’*

Answer (score 0):

The heart is usually symbolized as a thing of **love**.  Usually whenever something is said to be piercing the heart such as this it means that it hurts you emotionally.

I am assuming that this text means it is hurting this person emotionally.